# I want to add functionality User is not allowed to enter 0 as the first number in the Entry field

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to add functionality User is not allowed to enter 0 as the first number in the Entry field, please help me to solve the problem.

```
vcmd = (root.register(self.enter_only_digits),  '%P', '%d')
        self.text_num = tk.Entry(validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.text_num.place(x=100, y=210, width=100, height=20)

def enter_only_digits(self, entry, action_type) -> bool:
        if action_type == '1' and not entry.isdigit():
            return False

        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def enter_only_digits(self, entry, action_type) -> bool:
        if action_type == '1' and not entry.isdigit():
            return False
        if entry[0] == "0":
           print("not allowed to enter 0 as first number")

        return True
```

Comment: It works I want to know what this is -> bool

Comment: It sepcifies the return type, meaning this function must return a boolean.

Comment: If you input a digit (1 - 9) and then press `backspace`, then exception will be raised.

Comment: What do you mean @acw1668 ? The function takes as input an user input, there is not relation with any backspace that could cause an error

Comment: What I mean is that the validation will raise exception when user input a digit and then delete it.

Comment: Understood, I didnt pay much attention to the first part of the code

Answer (score 0):

since the entry is a string it can be checked if starting index contains 0 as:

```
def enter_only_digits(self, entry, action_type) -> bool:
        if action_type == '1' and not entry.isdigit() or entry[0] == "0":
            return False

        return True
```

Comment: If you input a digit (1 - 9) and then press `backspace`, then exception will be raised.

Comment: @acw1668 that I think need to be handled before ```enter_only_digits``` is called, it has nothing to do with the answer but OP's question.

Comment: What I mean is that the validation will raise exception when user input a digit and then delete it.